# How to remove the http:// removal from a string if it exists?

Tags: php, string

I know this is a simple thing but as I am a php novice I have yet to understand how to remove
something from an existing string.

I would like a string called domain that may or may not have `http://` with in it to have that `http://` removed?

Any help for the simple minded :)  Be nice...

Comment: [`parse_url`](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Speaking in tongues again I see. @Dagon - Cats have it so rough.

Comment: where as cats are indifferent to you.

Comment: All animals love me. That's what the alligator told me. @Dagon - (Especially the alligator).

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'http://www.google.com';
$str = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $str);
echo $str; // www.google.com
```

This will remove both http and https :).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can you explain why this example does both http:// and https://  ????

Comment: If you want to know how to use the operators in a preg_replace function, I can refer you to [php.com](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php). Scroll down to the part where it says: "The following should be escaped if you are trying to match that character:". It explains what each operator is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$d = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$d = str_replace('http://', '', $d);
```

Result:

```
$d => 'stackoverflow.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.validator.addMethod("domaincheck", function(val, elem) {if (val.length == 0){return true;}if(!/^(https?|ftp):///i.test(val)) {val = 'http://'+val;$(elem).val(val);}